# SQL update command not working, rows affected returns 0

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I have this method

```
public void Update(int id, string name)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        using (OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Students SET Name = @name WHERE ID = @id", databaseConnection))
        {
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            MessageBox.Show(update.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
        }
        CloseConnection();
    }
```

When it runs, I get 0 rows affected. I tried enclosing the command in a select block.

```
            using (OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = @id", databaseConnection))
        {
            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader())
            {
                using (OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Students SET Name = @name WHERE ID = @id", databaseConnection))
                {
                    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                    MessageBox.Show(update.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

When doing this, the message box still fires and gives 0 rows affected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there is a row with the `id` you provide? Does the `reader` contain anythinig?

Comment: Does the id exist in the database that you enter in the id parameter and are you setting the id variable? Check the sql inside the update prior to execution if you can.

Comment: @RenéVogt I set the ID to a constant to test and it still has the same result.

Comment: @ManoDestra I checked the database file and changed the ID to a constant, still throws 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 1):

Oledb does not accept named parameters.
Use "?" in replace for your named parameters and arrange your added values to match the position with respect to your query statement.

See this documentation.

[oledb parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It does support named paramaters. [Documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The documents says it uses positional parameters instead of name parameters refering to ur sql. Try replacing the named params with ? in your sql. And do AddWithValue(Atname,name) first b4 the id.